# Hosting Vapor Swift App on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: hosting, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, vapor

I have set up an Ubuntu instance on Google Cloud Platform and installed Swift-3 and Vapor on it. Then I tried to build the Vapor app with `vapor build` command and it succeeded. Then I run `vapor run` on the application folder, it successfully initiate the server and the console says that the service is available on local host, `0.0.0.0:8080`.

But when I enter the static ip of my VM in the browser window I am not able to see the vapor page I am supposed to. Instead I am getting a `connection refused` error.

Answer (score 5):

Port `80` is the default port for HTTP (non TLS) connections. It's likely that since Vapor is connecting to port `8080`, it is being blocked by a firewall.

Try doing `vapor run --port=80 --env=production` (you may need `sudo`)

This will set the port to `80` and will also set the environment to production to prevent any debug logging that could slow your application down.

EDIT:

Port configuration is done through the `Config/servers.json` file now.

```
{
    "default": {
        "port": 8080,
        "host": "localhost",
        "securityLayer": "none"
    }
}
```

However, you can still override through the command line interface with an updated command.

`--config:servers.default.port=8080`

Answer (score 3):

Have you opened this port in your Firewall Rules . Go to Networking and then "Firewall Rules" and check whether your port 8080 is listed there or not . If not, add it and then re-try visiting your vapour app . Hope this helps :)